# Android application: FB login re authentication issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

We have developed application which supports `Facebook login`. Our application is already there on **playstore**.

For some reason, our **Facebook developer** account is blocked. So we have created new **Facebook developer** account and created new application in it.

Using this new **Facebook application ID**, we have rebuild our `Android` application n roll out it in Beta.

After application **UPGRADE** from old to updated one, Its working fine on devices which does not have **Facebook** native application. Users are able to do **Facebook login** using updated application.

But its giving issue `Invalid key hash......` to users who have **Facebook** native application installed on their phones.

> Facebook developer blog says The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently
>   support re-authentication.

So any idea, how can I logout from Facebook problematically and application asks for re entering user **name and password**

Answer (score 0):

Have you update the Release Hash Key on the developer.facebook.com

your FB developer account may be block as it username doesn't matches with the real person name. It the policy of FB to disable FB account whos anme doesn't seen to be real name.

For the Invalid Key hash problem, upate your Release Hash Key on developer account your problem will be save.

Used this command in CMD to find the Release Hash Key.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias "Release_alias_name" -keystore "Release_Key_Store" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

Comment: Yes... I have updated the hash key and hence as mentioned

After application UPGRADE from old to updated one, Its working fine on devices which does not have Facebook native application. Users are able to do Facebook login using updated application..."

issue is there as we dnt have(atleast im not aware of any )any API to make reauthenticate FB users